# OPCODES WHY DOES free memory pointer(0X40) use 0x80 as starting value?

Tags: evm, opcode

The following opcodes **0x40** is "**offset in the memory in bytes**"

My question is why evm uses **0x80** as a "**32-byte value to write in the memory.**"

PUSH1 **0x80**

PUSH1 **0x40**

**MSTORE**

Sincerely

Answer (score 2):

The free memory pointer (stored at 0x40) starts at 0x80 simply because there are 4 32 byte slots at the start of memory that are reserved. From the Solidity docs on the [memory layout](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/internals/layout_in_memory.html):

- 0x00 - 0x3f (64 bytes): scratch space for hashing methods
- 0x40 - 0x5f (32 bytes): currently allocated memory size (aka. free memory pointer)
- 0x60 - 0x7f (32 bytes): zero slot

If the free memory pointer started any earlier than 0x80, it would interfere with these reserved slots (including the free memory pointer itself)

Answer (score 0):

**Free memory start location is 0x40**,

**0x80 value** indicates **this location**.

0x80=**128** decimals is equal to **64 bytes**

**64 bytes** is equal to **0x40**

***0x80 is decimal value but it indicates 0x40 location***